# How to perform $lookup between Stringified id and ObjectId in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

**Scenario**

I have to perform join on 2 collections named **college** and **student**.I am using **MongoDB 3.4**. Here, **college** has a field named `studentId` which references to `_id` of **student** collection.
The problem is that,`studentId` is already stored in stringified form whereas `_id` is the ObjectId.

> example of studentId: "5910193d4c00000a01c2c615"
>
> example of _id: ObjectId("59a931696d00007c0962e24a")

So, when I tried following **join query**:

```
db.college.aggregate(
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: "student",
           localField: "studentId",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "Related"
        }
    })
```

It doesn't work because **localField** `studentId` and **foreignField** `_id` are of different type. So, is there some way `studentId` be converted/compared to the `_id` so that a join operation could be performed?

Comment: You cannot. It's not possible to cast values in the aggregation framework. You need to fix the data that is presently a string and make them `ObjectId` values instead, so the local and foreign keys actually match.

Answer (score 0):

intent this :

```
college(studentId)  --- > student (_id)
 string             ---->     ObjectId


we need to convert to ObjectId

    db.college.aggregate([
     {
 "$addFields": {
    "newStudentId" :  { "$toObjectId": "$studentId" }
       }
    },{
        $lookup: {
           from: "student",
           localField: "newStudentId",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "Related"
        }
    }])
```

Comment: Hi, you can improve your answer greatly, by  inserting your code between [code tags](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and better code indentation. Take a look at SO [Markup Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded to mongodb 4.0. They have added the feature of converting object id to string by `"_id.str"` .
So your overall query could be like

```
db.college.aggregate(
{
    $lookup: {
       from: "student",
       localField: "studentId",
       foreignField: "_id.str",
       as: "Related"
    }
})
```

This should work well.